Distribute a flutter app outside of the App Store
My context:
I have

a mac (with xcode, ...)
an account on https://developer.apple.com
An account on https://appstoreconnect.apple.com
A Flutter application that builds, I can generate a signed ipa.

I would like to put my ipa online (personal website) and that ios (listed in "my devices" Apple, if necessary) can install it.
But I get lost with all the certificates and all the profiles. Whatever I do, it doesn't work. In the best case The app goes as far as installing itself but without being able to launch.
I build with: flutter build ipa --target lib/main_prd.dart --release --export-options-plist=ios/exportDevId.plist
My plist:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>compileBitcode</key>
<true/>
<key>uploadBitcode</key>
<true/>
<key>method</key>
<string>ios-application</string>
<key>destination</key>
<string>upload</string>
<key>teamID</key>
<string>Q3M.....G3</string>
<key>provisioningProfiles</key>
<dict>
<key>com.toto.totomobile</key>
<string>Ubysoil Mobile Developpement ID</string>
</dict>
<key>signingStyle</key>
<string>manual</string>
</dict>
</plist>

I can send the ipa to https://www.installonair.com/ but the app once installed does not launch "this app could not be installed because its integrity could not be installed"
No clear and up-to-date procedure on the web.
Can someone give me the exact types of certificates and profiles so that I can put my application on a remote IOS manually?
Thanks in advance.

At least for iOS, the only distribution is through the store, or TestDrive.  That'll soon change as the EU rules kicks in, permitting a limited number of third-party stores in the EU.

I am not sure if it will work or not, but you can try app distribution from firebase

Unfortunately there's no way around this, you will always have to have proper provisioning profiles and certificates to sign your build.
adhoc certificates require device UDIDs to be enrolled on your developer portal.
the other way is via testflight, but that would require other devices to have apple ids that are enrolled in your developer account
the last option is enterprise, but that requires a company with atleast 250 persons iirc

Ok, thank you for clear informations.
For firebase, it ask a too new version of XCode for me.
